# E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-stdr-simulator

Tags: ros, simulation, ros-jade, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried to install the stdr simulator, but I have encountered a problem. I have ROS Jade with Ubuntu 15.04
I tried to uninstall ROS completely and after that to install it again, like it was suggested here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/188732/e-unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-desktop-full/

This is what I get:

~$ sudo apt-get install ros-jade-stdr-simulator
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-stdr-simulator

I did of course - sudo apt-get update , before that.

What could it possibly be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233416/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-jade-stdr-simulator/) by [DI211](https://answers.ros.org/users/26747/di211/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error is likely telling you that the `stdr_simulator` package is not released on Jade. If you'd like to use the package and stick with 15.04+Jade, you'll need to build the package from source (at least for now). Check out [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/233177/how-can-i-install-vicon_bridge/?answer=233184#post-id-233184) I wrote a few days ago for more information.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1